# Getting error on npm start create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am currently learning React. I have done:

- `npm i -g create-react-app` (sucessful)
- `create-react-app react-app` (sucessful)
- `cd react-app`
- `npm start` (error above)

Output:

> - npm start \Git\cmd was unexpected .at this time.
> - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

So, what I have tried by searching online:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- delete node_modules
- delete package-lock.json
- `npm run clear`
- npm install

None solved. I have read that I should not installed globally but now that it is already instaled (?) can I rollback? I can't run npm i g create-react-app again.
Thank you

Edit: Added screenshot
https://i.ibb.co/mNKLskX/Capturar.png

Comment: Please post your package.json contents

Comment: Also, what OS are you using? Might be a permission issue if you are on Linux

Comment: `{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
`

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: I added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

with npm try `init`

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

or, try `npx`:

```
npx create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

npm start
```

Comment: It installs everything fine but npm start still gives the same error

Comment: try deleting node-module directory, package-lock.json and clear your cache and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the steps from 'create-react-app'?

`To create a new app, you may choose one of the following methods:

**npx**

```
 npx create-react-app my-app
```

(npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm versions)

**npm**

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

> npm init  is available in npm 6+

**Yarn**

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

> yarn create is available in Yarn 0.25+`

To have more info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Yes, it installs fine. The error comes at npm start